# Do comfortability degree/comfortability and comfort level/comfort have the same meaning?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-in-context

Hellow,

I would like to know how english native speakers interpret the words *comfortability degree/comfortability* vs. *comfort level/comfort* in contexts like the following:

a) Language competence can affect the *comfortability degree*/*comfortability* of non.native speakers.

b) Language competence can affect the *comfort level*/*comfor*t of non-native speakers.

Specifically I would like to know if the two pairs in a and b) are interchangable and if sentence b) is better than a).

Thanks!

Comment: Very few native speakers would use 'comfortability' when 'comfort' is available.

Comment: Thank you very much. Good to know.

Comment: Please **capitalize the names of languages**.

Answer (score 1):

"Comfortability" is probably a word to avoid if it can be replaced with "comfort".

So I'd prefer b) over a). I can't really see any real difference in meaning. And you should prefer the simple over the complex in formal writing.

Using "comfort level" seems possible if you mean the degree of comfort and not the type of comfort.  It does add something to the meaning, so it can be kept.

The overall meaning is somewhat unclear, though I assume you mean that if you are good at a language then you feel more at ease when speaking it.  A true, but rather trivial observation. If this is intended to mean something more than this, it could be clarified

Comment: Thank you very much for your very helpful reply. With "comfort level" I mean the degree of comfort. Perhaps I could also write "level of comfort"? Yes, I mean what you have assumed, but I want to indicate that there are various degrees of ease that is why I have thought of the word "comfort".

Comment: Yes "level of comfort" is a good possiblity.

Comment: OK. Thank you very much.